# Issiue with autopost to Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I see there is already a topic on this matter but no proper answer/solution to it.

I want to publish a blog to Facebook company page.

**Here is my code:**

```
function add($title, $text, $url, $path_to_image) {

    require_once("lib/facebook-autopost/facebook.php");

    $fb = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => 'APP_ID',
        'secret' => 'SECRET',
        'fileUpload' => false,
    ));

    $params = array(
        "access_token" => 'NEVER_ENDING_CODE', 
        "message" => "",
        "description" => $text,
        "link" =>  $url,
        "picture" => $path_to_image,
        "name" => $title,
        "caption" => $url
      );

    try{
         $fb->api("/FACEBOOKPAGE_ID/feed", 'POST', $params);

    }catch(Exception $e) {

         echo $e->getMessage();

    }
}
```

I’ve managed to follow this [guide](https://medium.com/@Jenananthan/how-to-create-non-expiry-facebook-page-token-6505c642d0b1) to find a guide to make a never-ending expiring token that have this permissions: `user_events, publish_actions, user_managed_groups, manage_pages, publish_pages, public_profile`.

Now when I try to post to Facebook I get this error:

```
(#100) Only owners of the URL have the ability to specify the picture, name, thumbnail or description params.
```

I have also added the domain to the Facebook business manager, confirmed the domain and added the Facebook page to the domain.

Any help on getting the auto post working is appreciated

Comment: Did you complete all the necessary steps listed under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification#implementation ? (Which way did you choose? DNS, HTML file, OG tags?) Have you checked the result via debug tool?

Comment: Yes, i did all that and its confirmed :) it seams it posts to wall when i just have link + message, but i cant send images, title and description